# Trouble uploading file to web server in Unity

Tags: c#, perl, file-upload, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble getting my files to upload in Unity. I've written a class that saves a screenshot to my local disk and then uploads it to my server through a cgi script. I'm not getting errors but when I check the uploads folder on my web server the file is not there. What am I getting wrong here?

Unity C#

```
// Saves screenshot as JPG file.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class CreateJPG : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public int startX = 0;
    public int endX = 1050;
    public int startY = 0;
    public int endY = 700;

    public string screenShotURL= "http://locomoku.com/projects/samnoble/strangecreatures/cgi-bin/upload.cgi";

    string fileName;
    string filePath;
    // Texture2D tex;

    public void GrabJPG () {
        StartCoroutine(SaveJPG());
    }

    IEnumerator SaveJPG()
    {   
        // We should only read the screen buffer after rendering is complete
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(endX, endY, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(startX,startY,endX,endY),0,0);
        tex.Apply();

        // Encode texture into JPG
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToJPG(50);
        Object.Destroy(tex);

        // Get filePrefix from GameSetup array index
        GameObject init = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Initializer");
        GameSetup gameSetup = init.GetComponent<GameSetup>();
        string prefix = gameSetup.filePrefix;
        string subDir = gameSetup.subDir;

        string dtString = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmssfff");
        fileName = prefix+dtString+".jpg";
        filePath = @"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/"+subDir+"/";

        // If screenshot is > 0 x 0 write bytes
        if(endX > 0 && endY > 0)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath+fileName, bytes);
            Debug.Log("Your file was saved at " + filePath+fileName);
        }

        // Create a Web Form
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("frameCount", Time.frameCount.ToString());
        form.AddBinaryData("fileUpload", bytes, fileName, "image/jpg");

        // Upload to a cgi script
        WWW w = new WWW(screenShotURL, form);
        yield return w;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.error)) {
            print(w.error);
        }
        else {
            print("Finished Uploading " + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

CGI Script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;
$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;

my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
my $upload_dir = "/home/locomoku/public_html/projects/samnoble/strangecreatures/uploads";
my $query = new CGI;
my $filename = $query->param("photo");
my $email_address = $query->param("email_address");

if ( !$filename )
    {
        print $query->header ( );
        print "There was a problem uploading your photo (try a smaller file).";
        exit;
    }

my ($name, $path) = fileparse($filename);
$filename = $name;
$filename =~ tr/ /_/;
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;

if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ )
    {
        $filename = $1;
    }
    else
    {
        die "Filename contains invalid characters";
    }

my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo");
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "Can't open $upload_dir/$filename: $!";
binmode UPLOADFILE;

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
    {
        print UPLOADFILE;
    }

close UPLOADFILE;
print $query->header ( );
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mismatch between the two programs.

Your C++ program is setting CGI parameters called 'frameCount' and 'fileUpload'. But your Perl program is expecting parameters called 'photo' and 'email_address'. I can't see how these two programs can possibly work together.

I can't give any help on your C++ code, but your Perl program is written in a fashion that went out of date fifteen year ago.

- Instead of "-w" on the shebang line, we now put `use warnings` in our code.
- `new CGI` is a syntax that should largely be avoided (as "new" is not a keyword in Perl - it's just a method name). `CGI->new` is safer.
- You should use the three-argument form of `open()` along with lexical filehandles.

  open ( my $upload_fh, '>', "$upload_dir/$filename" )
    or die "Can't open $upload_dir/$filename: $!";